# The variable is undefined before using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a big problem and I can not find out it at all. Please help me.

Here is the code in the view:

```
@{var imageName = Mission.UI.Areas.Cpanel.Components.Utility.GetDocument(Model.EmployeeId, Mission.Model.DocType.Aks);}
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mission.UI.Areas.Cpanel.Components.Utility.GetDocument(Model.EmployeeId, Mission.Model.DocType.Aks)))
{
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label style="display:block;">عکس</label><img src="/files/@imageName" class="thumbnail col-lg-12" style="height:280px;" />
    </div>
}
```

The `GetDocument` method is returning correct name but when I use it in img src it is undefined.

This is the Method:

```
public static string GetDocument(string employeeId, DocType docType)
{
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepo = new EmployeeRepository();
    var document = employeeRepo.GetDocuments(employeeId).Where(d => d.DocType == docType).FirstOrDefault();
    if (document != null)
    {
        return document.Content;
    }
    return "";
}
```

And the returning value is fetched in the view but when I set it in src it is undefiend but when I show it in a span there is no problem.

What is the problem all?

Comment: What is returning ? can you post the value of it ?

Comment: So if `imageName` has the correct value, why don't you just do `<img src="@imageName" ...`?

Comment: Which line is triggering the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the same function multiple times which is wrong and completely inefficient. Just use the variable `imageName` :

```
@{
   var imageName = Mission.UI.Areas.Cpanel.Components.Utility.GetDocument(Model.EmployeeId, Mission.Model.DocType.Aks);
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
   {
      string imagePath = @"/files/" + imageName;

      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <label style="display:block;">عکس</label><img src="@imagePath" 
                class="thumbnail col-lg-12" style="height:280px;" />
      </div>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try this?

```
@{
   var imageName = Mission.UI.Areas.Cpanel.Components.Utility.GetDocument(Model.EmployeeId, Mission.Model.DocType.Aks);
}

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
{
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label style="display:block;">عکس</label><img src="/files/@{imageName}" class="thumbnail col-lg-12" style="height:280px;" />
</div>
}
```